# SQL Select Statement with If Else

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, if-statement

I have the following sql statement below but however I want to increase the discount to 30 %, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90% instead of 20% if the price is over 1000.

if the price is over 1000, the the discount level is increased by 20%. So if the discount applied is 10%, then the 10% is itself increased 20%. So 20% of 10% is 2%, and the over 1000 price is therefore discounted at 12%.

if the price is above 440 less than 1000, apply the standard discount in the table.

if the price is 440 or below, no discount is applied.

```
SELECT ItemID, Title,
round(
  if(price >= 1000, price * (100 - ($price_discounts * 1.2))/100,  
  if(price < 1000 and price > 440, price * (100 - $price_discounts) /100, price))
,2)
as SalePrice, price
FROM alldata;
```

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms182717.aspx       You can have an if statement and then run the appropriate select statement based off that

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  The answer may be platform dependent.

Comment: @Gage That's procedural `IF`.  This is the [`IF()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634824.aspx).

Comment: I know how to use the if function or case but however I dont know how to change the discount from 20% to 30%, 40% - all the way to 90% as I am pretty rubbish at maths, that is my question. for example 20% is 1.2 but I need help for the others and I know 10% is 0.9.

Comment: How does the discount scale to 30%, 40%, etc?  Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't follow what you're trying to do

Comment: Why not make a small table with the ranges and the percent discount?  Then you could join on a between and get the percent to multiply.

Comment: I dont know how to do the discount for 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%,80% or 90%

Comment: could anybody help me how I change the price discount to 30%, 40% or 50%

Comment: How do you determine what the initial discount is?  The original discount is `$price_discounts`?  I understand how you increase from 10% to 12%.  But I dont understand how you would increase from 10% to 13.3%

Comment: $price_discounts * 1.2) means 20% discount but however I want to change 1.2 to 30%, 40%, 50%,60%,70%,80% and 90% one by one.

Comment: Multiplying by 1.2 means that you are multiplying by 120%.  To look at it another way its the same as *adding* 20% to the value.  If you want to add 30% to your value, you multiply by 1.3.  40% = 1.4 etc.

Comment: so 50% is 1.5, 60% 1.6, 70% 1.7,, 80% 1.8 and 90% 1.9. Is this correct.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  Multiplying by 2 would be a 100% increase.  A 100% increase, means that your value has doubled.

Comment: Hi Pagogomex Thank You so much for this, This was only my question.

Comment: This was phrased like you needed sql help.  In future, with math problems you may want to check out [math.se].  More importantly however, make sure your question asks the problem you have.  Learning how to phrase a good question is a skill that every developer should learn. See [ask] for more.